# Click in JS loop undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an interation loop on which I need to click on every element:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('span')
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i += 1) {
    i.click(function() {
      console.log("Clicked")
    });
}
```

I get `i.click is not a function` error. ¿What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: `i` is a number not an element.

Comment: How can I reference the element in i?

Comment: `spans[i].click()`. Note that it doesn’t accept any arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: You need to do a for each loop through `spans` array. Spans array will have elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the *index*, not the element. This is how you would fix your code:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('span')
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i += 1) {
  spans[i].click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked")
  });
}
```

But 'click' also doesn't take a callback. This is how your code *should* look like in 2022:

```
const spans = document.getElementsByClassName('span')
for (const span of spans) {
  span.click();
  console.log("Clicked")
}
```

Comment: `console.log` will only print through each iteration.

Comment: @ShamshadZaheer I mainly just tried to mimic what I think the intent was of the original code, which also had a call to `console.log()` for each iteration.